# Perturbation Theory with no symmetry breaking?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, perturbation-theory, symmetry-breaking

I was learing about group theory in QM and stable about symmetry breaking. I find it very interesting and search some stuff and even looked on wikipedia and found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_symmetry_breaking.

At the bottom I saw that the perturbation term "is the term which explicitly breaks the symmetry".

My question is: If we use a non-breaking symmetry term for the perturbation do we get significantly different results?

For example I know that in the Zeeman Effect we can separate energy levels further with the help of an external magnetic field, because I know assume that the added field breaks a symmetry of rotation because of its direction. Can this kind of result be expected in a perturbation with no symmetry breaking.

Also, if you have any book recommendations for this kind of subject I will be glad if you can send it!

Comment: The main result of "symmetry breaking" here is that degenerate states (connected by the symmetry operation, hence same energy) are split, i.e. their energies are now different. Of course, if the perturbation respects the symmtry, the degeneracy is still there. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't know if this is how it works for sure, and I can't really imagine a scenario to make the calculation to check for myself.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is the following: A symmetry transformation is represented by an operator $U$ that commutes with the Hamiltonian, $\left[H,U\right]=0$. Note that generally, $U$ can be a discrete transformation (such as a reflection) or depend on an continuous parameter (such as a rotation).

Now, for any energy eigenstate $\left|\psi\right>$, i.e. $H\left|\psi\right>=E\left|\psi\right>$, we have
$$ H \left(U \left|\psi\right>\right)= H U \left|\psi\right>= U H \left|\psi\right>=U E \left|\psi\right>= E\left(U\left|\psi\right>\right)\,.$$
In other words, $U\left|\psi\right>$ is again an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with the same energy.

Now, it may happen that $U\left|\psi\right>=\left|\psi\right>$ (what one would often call a "singlet state"), but most of the time, they are different, so we now have two (or more) states with the same energy, i.e. a degeneracy.

If we now add an extra term to the Hamiltonian to get $H'=H+\Delta H$,thee are basically two possibilities:

- $\Delta H$ respects the symmetry, i.e. $\left[\Delta H,U\right]=0$. Then the above argument still goes through as before, and we have degenerate energy eigenstates.
- Else, $\left[\Delta H,U\right]\neq0$, and in general, $H'\left(U\left|\psi\right>\right)\neq H'\left|\psi\right>$, i.e. the symmetry is broken.

Note that the pattern of symmetry breaking can be quite complicated, as the perturbation $\Delta H$ may respect some of the symmetries of $H$, but not all. This is the main appplication of group and representation theory in physics.